# Helm Chart install error: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm trying to install the `kube-prometheus-stack` chart by running:

```sh
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  -f ./prometheus-operator-values.yaml
```

But I get the error:

```
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
Error: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition
```

The chart requires `Kubernetes 1.16+`, I'm on a lokal Minikube cluster, when I check the version with `kubectl version`, I get:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:32:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.21) and server (1.19) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

So my version should meet the requirements, right?

If so, what other reasons could this error have?

Comment: hi @Jonas, could you please share the tutorial you are following to install this or the yaml file so I can reproduce your issue? thanks

Comment: @Bazhikov all I did was create a Minucube cluster, added the the repo with `helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts`, then install the chart with `helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack`

Comment: @Jonas, I hope your problem has been resolved since you posted the question a long time ago. Can you post and accept the procedure followed as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a **known issue** in GitHub, please refer to the [existing bug](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/1041) and place a comment there in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the same issue as I'm having, because in the issue it works sometimes and happens when upgrading the chart. For me it never works and it happens when installing the chart

Comment: @Jonas, could you please provide me what minikube driver you use? Please refer this: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/

Comment: @Bazhikov I'm using docker as the vm driver

Comment: @Jonas, I've tried to reproduce your issue on new centos cluster using docker and minikube, however the charts were installed for me, Could you please provide me with your minikube config?

Answer (score 0):

it is kinda weird but I use 15.0.0 version and start to work. downgrade version. I was trying to download versions 27, 28 and finally end up with 15. and its start to run. I used the same repo.